# bootstrap grid with border between columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-grid

How can i make a bootstrap grid with one row and inside that 2 columns. First column size 9 col-md-9 and the second size 3 col-md-3 that no matter how long the content will be inside the columns the row and columns will be nice and border between them. How can I do it? It should look like this:

[image]

Not like this:

[image]

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Gt25L/1272/)

```css
.row > div {
  background: lightgrey;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='row'>
  <div class="col-xs-9">
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>  <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>  <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
 
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

An universal solution would be to use flexbox.

This will allow your columns to have always equal height.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Gt25L/1280/
(I supposed you'd have to add specific class, because `rows` and `cols` are too general, but I believe you got the point)

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}

.row > div {
  flex: 1;
  background: lightgrey;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div class='row'>
  <div class="col-xs-9">
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>  <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>  <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
 
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: but if we have specifying there with two more columns without specifying row its not well display; like https://jsfiddle.net/wnqb1L23/1/  ; is there any way for the same

Answer (score 3):

Slightly ghetto, but you could use background color on the row, not the columns, and add a border on just one of the columns (assuming you're always going to have more content on the left column)

https://jsfiddle.net/Gt25L/1277/

```
<div class="container">
<div class='row'>
  <div class="col-xs-9 border">
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br> Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>  <br>Hifgdfgsdfg

  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
.row {
  background: lightgrey;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.border {
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use boostrap4 (flexbox) or play around with box-shadow to draw borders and set background into the parent container :

Drawing inset and outset shadows will make them overlap so you will not notice wich is the tallest box.

```css
.row {
  background: lightgrey;
  border-top: 2px solid grey;
  box-shadow: 0 2px grey, inset 2px 0 gray, inset -2px 0 grey;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.row>div {
  box-shadow: 2px 0 grey, inset 2px 0 grey
}


/* demo purpose*/

.row {
  margin: auto!important;
  max-width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class='row'>
  <div class="col-xs-9">
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br> <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br> <br>Hifgdfgsdfg

  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
<div class='row'>
  <div class="col-xs-3">Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-9">
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br> <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br> <br>Hifgdfgsdfg

  </div>
</div>
```

---

about [bootsrap 4](https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/utilities/flexbox/) https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/

```css
.row>div {
  background: lightgrey;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="container">
  <div class='row'>
    <div class="col-9 col-xs-9">
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br> <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br> <br>Hifgdfgsdfg

    </div>
    <div class="col-3 col-xs-3">Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='row d-flex'>
    <div class="col-3 col-xs-3">Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br>
    </div>
    <div class="col-9 col-xs-9">
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br> <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br> <br>Hifgdfgsdfg

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `<div class="col-xs-offset-1">` wrapping the text to offset it, avoiding any extra CSS. See the snippet below:

```css
.row > div {
  background: lightgrey;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class='row'>
  <div class="col-xs-9">
     <div class="col-xs-offset-1">
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>  <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>  <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-3">
     <div class="col-xs-offset-1">
        Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    <br>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't mind specifying the width of one of the elements, you can use a negative margin, then increase the width by the margin amount.

```css
.row > div {
  background: lightgrey;
  border: 1px solid grey;
}

.row > div:last-child {
  margin-left: -1px;
  width: calc(25% + 1px);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class='row'>
    <div class="col-xs-9">
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br>
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br>
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg

    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3">Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg

      <br>
      <br>Hifgdfgsdfg
    </div>
  </div>
```